# Java Spring Boot Rest: Search objects by specific parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-rest

I have this student app with grades and exams, what I need to do is to find all exams for specific date and function to list average grade for a specific exam.

Here are entity classes for Student, Exam and Grade

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String firstname;

    private String lastname;

    private String branch;

    private int year;

    private String studentsIndex;
}

@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Exam {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    private String code;

    private LocalDate date;

    private String time;

    private String classroom;
}

@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Grade {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Exam exam;

    @ManyToOne
    private Student student;

    @Column(name = "Grade")
    private int grade;

}
```

I have repositories for all of them, but I have not added any other methods to them. Also, I have services for finding all, finding by id, deleting by id, etc...

So my question is how and what do I need to do so I can get all exams for a specific date and average grade for a certain exam, what do I need to add to the repository and service, and how to create that GET method in Controller class?

By the way, I am saving grades through the DTO object which contains an exam id and also one for student and grade.

Comment: you will need to write the code that makes those searches in your DB, stores the data in a response object, and return it to the client

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I can't test the code at the moment. I would do both selection and aggregation for performance reasons in the database or via JPA. BTW, I assume you're using Spring Data JPA...

The first approach would be to turn a unidirectional JPA mapping into a bidirectional mapping. For this purpose, an association is created in the `Exam` class using `@OneToMany`.

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Exam {

    // Rest of your class...

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "exam")
    private List<Grade> grades;
}
```

Next you have to write a custom query for your `ExamRepository`. For this, you should create projection.

```
public interface IExamGradeAverage {
    Long getExamId();
    Double getGradeAverage();
}
```

This projection is used as return typ of your custom query.

```
@Repository
public interface ExamRepository extends JpaRepository<Exam, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT e.id AS examId, AVG(g.grade) AS gradeAverage FROM Exam e JOIN e.grades g WHERE e.date = ?1")
    List<IExamGradeAverage> getAverageGradeOfExamByDate(LocalDate date);
}
```

After that, theoretically a rest endpoint could be created that uses the JPA repository implementation t fetch the aggregation.